# AngularJS show message about non-valid value in non-required field

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have next markup:

```
<input type="number" name="test" ng-model="data.test" step="any" ng-pattern="/^\d*[\.|,]?\d*$/" />
<span class="error" ng-show="!editForm.test.$valid || editForm.test.$error">Please, enter valid decimal number, such as 15.6</span>
```

When I am editing value in this input tag, message about non-valid value (in span tag) doesn't shown and after form submitting value will be set to null. When I am wrote required attribute to this input, message was shown, but this field is not required for me. How I can force AngularJS to show error message without required attribute?

**EDIT:**
1. Sorry, $error doesn't work properly
2. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9w2HZ/. Type in first field non-number, in next non-number too and then you can see different.

Comment: please add a plunkr or jsfiddle of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jsFiddle, in the first case, strangely if you use type="text", then the validation error shows up correctly and in the developer tools, you will see that ng-invalid-pattern is added to the input.

If you look into developer tools, in the second case too, if you give any invalid number, the class ng-invalid-required is added to the input rather than ng-invalid-pattern.

If there is no specific reason for using type=number, maybe just use type=text for the input control.

Comment: I need use type="number" and then, in first field have ng-valid and ng-valid-pattern classes, but in field I typed string expression without numbers.